# In Google Maps iOS how to turn Marker as per turns on road like in Uber's Trip screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on an iOS application that works like [Uber](https://www.uber.com/). When the device moves I am moving the car marker as well. But am not able to turn it as per turns on road like Uber does. How can I make it possible?
Also how can I keep this car marker only on road?

Comment: Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate bearing then rotate marker based on the calculated bearing.
Use this function to calculate bearing:

```
+(float)getBearing:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locations1 andSecond:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locattion2
{
    float fLat = degreesToRadians(locations1.latitude);
    float fLng = degreesToRadians(locations1.longitude);
    float tLat = degreesToRadians(locattion2.latitude);
    float tLng = degreesToRadians(locattion2.longitude);

    float degree = radiansToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        return degree;
    } else {
        return 360+degree;
    }
}
```

Then rotate the marker itself using rotation property

```
marker.rotation = CALCULATED_BEARING - 180;
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [rotating the marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#rotate_a_marker) alongside the update or the moving of locations with regards to the [bearing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views#bearing_orientation). Not really sure how you can achieve with keeping the marker on the road since you are relying on the gps to provide exact location where you will place your marker.

Take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154489/googlemap-marker-rotation-position-changes) as a sample.