# googleMap marker rotation position changes

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using overlay as marker, and here is my below code which I created.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <title>Label Overlay Example</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 function initialize() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100)
    ,  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    })
    ,   goldStar = {
        path: 'M57.996 -29.483q0 1.836 -1.332 3.24l-2.7 2.7q-1.368 1.368 -3.276 1.368 -1.944 0 -3.24 -1.368l-10.584 -10.548v25.344q0 1.872 -1.35 3.042t-3.258 1.17h-4.608q-1.908 0 -3.258 -1.17t-1.35 -3.042v-25.344l-10.584 10.548q-1.296 1.368 -3.24 1.368t-3.24 -1.368l-2.7 -2.7q-1.368 -1.368 -1.368 -3.24 0 -1.908 1.368 -3.276l23.436 -23.436q1.26 -1.332 3.24 -1.332 1.944 0 3.276 1.332l23.436 23.436q1.332 1.404 1.332 3.276z', 
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 5,
        scale: 0.2,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        rotation: 190,
        anchor: google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    size: google.maps.Size(-8, -8)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: goldStar
    });

    var label = new Label({
        map: map
    });

    label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
    label.bindTo('text', marker, 'position');
};


function Label(opt_options) {
    this.setValues(opt_options);
    var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.cssText = 'width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 100%; position: absolute;' +
                     'background-color: #8dc73f; ';
};

Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
Label.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    var pane = this.getPanes().overlayLayer;
    pane.appendChild(this.div_);
};

Label.prototype.draw = function() {
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = position.x - 17 + 'px';
    div.style.top = position.y - 6 +'px';
    div.style.display = 'block';
};

 </head>

<body onload="initialize()">
   <div id="map_canvas"  style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As the in above code I created a custom marker, Mean-while I added a rotation for the path, when ever the marker rotation is changed to other than 190, suppose 60, 45, 230, 270. the direction path icon is displaying in a different place.

Currently rotation: 190 will work fine.

How can I set the rotation of the marker to be set relative to the markerlabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your circle so it is centered on the position of where you want the marker. It is 20x20, so center it at 10,10:

```
function Label(opt_options) {
  this.setValues(opt_options);
  var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.cssText = 'width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 100%; position: absolute;' +
    'background-color: #8dc73f; ';
};

//

Label.prototype.draw = function() {
  var projection = this.getProjection();
  var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = position.x - 10 + 'px';
  div.style.top = position.y - 10 + 'px';
  div.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Then set the anchor appropriately (at its center as well so it can rotate and still be in the center of the circle).

```
goldStar = {
  path: 'M57.996 -29.483q0 1.836 -1.332 3.24l-2.7 2.7q-1.368 1.368 -3.276 1.368 -1.944 0 -3.24 -1.368l-10.584 -10.548v25.344q0 1.872 -1.35 3.042t-3.258 1.17h-4.608q-1.908 0 -3.258 -1.17t-1.35 -3.042v-25.344l-10.584 10.548q-1.296 1.368 -3.24 1.368t-3.24 -1.368l-2.7 -2.7q-1.368 -1.368 -1.368 -3.24 0 -1.908 1.368 -3.276l23.436 -23.436q1.26 -1.332 3.24 -1.332 1.944 0 3.276 1.332l23.436 23.436q1.332 1.404 1.332 3.276z',
  fillColor: 'red',
  fillOpacity: 5,
  scale: 0.2,
  strokeWeight: 0,
  rotation: 190,
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(30,-30)
};
```

related questions:

- [Change marker icon options in google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149817/change-marker-icon-options-in-google-maps)
- [Centering google maps SymbolPath on LatLon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254425/centering-google-maps-symbolpath-on-latlon)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5fg6t2ek/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 15,
      center: latLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }),
    goldStar = {
      path: 'M57.996 -29.483q0 1.836 -1.332 3.24l-2.7 2.7q-1.368 1.368 -3.276 1.368 -1.944 0 -3.24 -1.368l-10.584 -10.548v25.344q0 1.872 -1.35 3.042t-3.258 1.17h-4.608q-1.908 0 -3.258 -1.17t-1.35 -3.042v-25.344l-10.584 10.548q-1.296 1.368 -3.24 1.368t-3.24 -1.368l-2.7 -2.7q-1.368 -1.368 -1.368 -3.24 0 -1.908 1.368 -3.276l23.436 -23.436q1.26 -1.332 3.24 -1.332 1.944 0 3.276 1.332l23.436 23.436q1.332 1.404 1.332 3.276z',
      fillColor: 'red',
      fillOpacity: 5,
      scale: 0.2,
      strokeWeight: 0,
      rotation: 190,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, -30)
    };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: goldStar,

  });

  var label = new Label({
    map: map
  });

  label.bindTo('position', marker, 'position');
  label.bindTo('text', marker, 'position');
  var rotation = 190;
  setInterval(function() {
    rotation += 20;
    goldStar.rotation = rotation;
    marker.setIcon(goldStar);
  }, 1000);
};


function Label(opt_options) {
  this.setValues(opt_options);
  var div = this.div_ = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.cssText = 'width: 20px; height: 20px; border-radius: 100%; position: absolute;' +
    'background-color: #8dc73f; ';
};

Label.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;
Label.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var pane = this.getPanes().overlayLayer;
  pane.appendChild(this.div_);
};

Label.prototype.draw = function() {
  var projection = this.getProjection();
  var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.get('position'));

  var div = this.div_;
  div.style.left = position.x - 10 + 'px';
  div.style.top = position.y - 10 + 'px';
  div.style.display = 'block';
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```