# Android set marker rotation according to destination

Tags: android, google-maps

This is my code so far and is changing the rotation of the marker regarding the position of the tablet.

```
float[] mGravity;
float[] mGeomagnetic;
Float azimut;
Marker Mymarker;
MarkerOptions MyMarkerOption = new MarkerOptions();

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(GotLocation){

        if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);

            MyLocation = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                azimut = orientation[0];

                float azimuthInRadians = orientation[0];
                float azimuthInDegress = (float)(Math.toDegrees(azimuthInRadians)+360)%360;

                if(location_marker == 0){
                    MyMarkerOption.position(MyLocation);
                    Mymarker = map.addMarker(MyMarkerOption);
                    location_marker++;
                }

                Mymarker.setPosition(MyLocation);
                Mymarker.setRotation(azimuthInDegress);
                Mymarker.setFlat(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like that the rotation of the marker changes regarding a given lat-long position. So I guess that now the algorithm is calculating the **azimuthInDegress** regarding the tablet. I would like that it calculates it regarding a given point.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308262/calculate-compass-bearing-heading-to-location-in-android) where someone was asking the same thing, but I do not know how to implement this solution for my code..The thread is also 5 years old so maybe there is another solution right now.

Comment: Have you  check this SO ticket? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154489/googlemap-marker-rotation-position-changes

Comment: This is javascript and it does not look like what I am searching for..I did something that should work but haven't tested it jet..